# Дебиан не загружается

Tags: debian

Каждый раз запуская виртуалку у меня выдает это, гугл никак не помогает, а в виртуалке очень важные данные, уже не знаю что делать

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VIm.png

Comment: так отключите загрузку этого `brltty.service`, добавив к командной строке программы *linux* что-нибудь типа `systemd.mask=brltty` или `systemd.mask=brltty.service` или как-то в этом духе. а загрузившись, вообще его удалите, чтоб не мешался (если вы, конечно, не используете каких-нибудь брайлевских устройств)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как можно что то добавить к командной строке, просто ввести в терминале?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter